# QuickBlox WebRTC iOS: can't connect properly

Tags: ios, quickblox

I'm trying to create an iOS application with video chat, using QuickBlox-WebRTC.

My controller is a `QBRTCClientDelegate` and everything seems to work "kind of well". The following calls are hit (not in order):

- `didReceiveNewSession`
- `initializedLocalMediaStream`
- `receivedRemoteVideoTrack`
- `acceptedByUser`

But unfortunately, `startedConnectingToUser` and `connectedToUser` never happens.

On the caller side, I see the following in the logs:

```
2016-02-09 23:28:38:105 TestProject[1194:4052297] rtc::Did receive signal: accept from: 8760016
2016-02-09 23:28:38:158 TestProject[1194:4052328] rtc::Did receive signal: iceCandidates from: 8760016
2016-02-09 23:28:38:259 TestProject[1194:4052295] rtc::Did receive signal: iceCandidates from: 8760016
2016-02-09 23:28:38:262 TestProject[1194:4052295] rtc::Did receive signal: iceCandidates from: 8760016
2016-02-09 23:28:38:318 TestProject[1194:4052295] rtc::Did receive signal: iceCandidates from: 8760016
2016-02-09 23:28:38:412 TestProject[1194:4052327] rtc::Did receive signal: iceCandidates from: 8760016
2016-02-09 23:28:40:878 TestProject[1194:4052297] rtc::<Peer:0x155793250, UID:8760016, r:Offer> Send local offer sdp
2016-02-09 23:28:45:839 TestProject[1194:4052297] rtc::<Peer:0x155793250, UID:8760016, r:Offer> Send local offer sdp
2016-02-09 23:28:50:876 TestProject[1194:4052299] rtc::<Peer:0x155793250, UID:8760016, r:Offer> Send local offer sdp
2016-02-09 23:28:55:865 TestProject[1194:4052297] rtc::Close connection for user 8760016
2016-02-09 23:28:55:866 TestProject[1194:4052297] rtc::Invalidate timer:dialing timer, background task id 5 ...
2016-02-09 23:28:55:874 TestProject[1194:4052308] rtc::<Peer:0x155793250, UID:8760016, r:Offer> Renegotiation needed
2016-02-09 23:28:55:876 TestProject[1194:4052297] rtc::<Peer:0x155793250, UID:8760016, r:Offer> Remove local media stream: [com.quickblox.mediastream.device-iphone.6.plus_ios-9.2.1_userid-8762474]:A=1:V=1]
2016-02-09 23:28:55.897 TestProject[1194:4052297] dealloc QBRTCLocalAudioTrack
2016-02-09 23:28:55:896 TestProject[1194:4052297] rtc::<Peer:0x155793250, UID:8760016, r:Offer> Ice connection change:Closed
2016-02-09 23:28:55.897 TestProject[1194:4052297] dealloc QBRTCLocalVideoTrack
2016-02-09 23:28:55:898 TestProject[1194:4052307] rtc::Stop rtc video capturer
2016-02-09 23:28:55.902 TestProject[1194:4052297] Destroy local media stream
2016-02-09 23:28:55:902 TestProject[1194:4052297] rtc::<Peer:0x155793250, UID:8760016, r:Offer> Signaling state changed: Closed
2016-02-09 23:28:55:902 TestProject[1194:4052297] rtc::Destroy dialing timer
```

On the callee side, I see the following:

```
2016-02-09 23:28:36:418 TestProject[97959:2233683] rtc::<Peer:0x7fbbe3b54cb0, UID:8762474, r:Answer> Signaling state changed: Stable
2016-02-09 23:28:36:418 TestProject[97959:2233683] rtc::<Peer:0x7fbbe3b54cb0, UID:8762474, r:Answer> Send queued ICE candidates, count: 0
2016-02-09 23:28:37:500 TestProject[97959:2233685] rtc::<Peer:0x7fbbe3b54cb0, UID:8762474, r:Answer> ICE gathering changed: Gathering
2016-02-09 23:28:37:500 TestProject[97959:2234170] rtc::<Peer:0x7fbbe3b54cb0, UID:8762474, r:Answer> Set session description
2016-02-09 23:28:37:500 TestProject[97959:2234170] rtc::Send Answer: <Peer:0x7fbbe3b54cb0, UID:8762474, r:Answer>
2016-02-09 23:28:37:500 TestProject[97959:2234170] rtc::<Peer:0x7fbbe3b54cb0, UID:8762474, r:Answer> Queued ICE candidates, count: 0
2016-02-09 23:28:37:500 TestProject[97959:2234170] rtc::<Peer:0x7fbbe3b54cb0, UID:8762474, r:Answer> Send queued ICE candidates, count: 1
2016-02-09 23:28:37:612 TestProject[97959:2234066] rtc::<Peer:0x7fbbe3b54cb0, UID:8762474, r:Answer> Queued ICE candidates, count: 0
2016-02-09 23:28:37:613 TestProject[97959:2234066] rtc::<Peer:0x7fbbe3b54cb0, UID:8762474, r:Answer> Send queued ICE candidates, count: 1
2016-02-09 23:28:37:706 TestProject[97959:2234170] rtc::<Peer:0x7fbbe3b54cb0, UID:8762474, r:Answer> Queued ICE candidates, count: 0
2016-02-09 23:28:37:706 TestProject[97959:2234170] rtc::<Peer:0x7fbbe3b54cb0, UID:8762474, r:Answer> Send queued ICE candidates, count: 1
2016-02-09 23:28:37:881 TestProject[97959:2234173] rtc::<Peer:0x7fbbe3b54cb0, UID:8762474, r:Answer> Queued ICE candidates, count: 0
2016-02-09 23:28:37:881 TestProject[97959:2234173] rtc::<Peer:0x7fbbe3b54cb0, UID:8762474, r:Answer> Send queued ICE candidates, count: 1
2016-02-09 23:28:38:131 TestProject[97959:2233685] rtc::<Peer:0x7fbbe3b54cb0, UID:8762474, r:Answer> ICE gathering changed: Complete
2016-02-09 23:28:38:132 TestProject[97959:2234172] rtc::<Peer:0x7fbbe3b54cb0, UID:8762474, r:Answer> Queued ICE candidates, count: 0
2016-02-09 23:28:38:132 TestProject[97959:2234172] rtc::<Peer:0x7fbbe3b54cb0, UID:8762474, r:Answer> Send queued ICE candidates, count: 1
2016-02-09 23:28:41:914 TestProject[97959:2234172] rtc::Did receive signal: call from: 8762474
2016-02-09 23:28:41:914 TestProject[97959:2234172] rtc::<Peer:0x7fbbe3b54cb0, UID:8762474, r:Answer> Queued Remote SDP
2016-02-09 23:28:46:708 TestProject[97959:2234172] rtc::Did receive signal: call from: 8762474
2016-02-09 23:28:46:709 TestProject[97959:2234170] rtc::<Peer:0x7fbbe3b54cb0, UID:8762474, r:Answer> Queued Remote SDP
2016-02-09 23:28:51:891 TestProject[97959:2234170] rtc::Did receive signal: call from: 8762474
2016-02-09 23:28:51:891 TestProject[97959:2233683] rtc::<Peer:0x7fbbe3b54cb0, UID:8762474, r:Answer> Queued Remote SDP
```

...and it repeats the last two rows.

I've checked how it happens in the sample application and it seems my app never gets to the part when the following happens:

```
2016-02-09 12:48:49:006 sample-videochat-webrtc[278:20551] rtc::Did receive signal: iceCandidates from: 2436266
2016-02-09 12:48:49:007 sample-videochat-webrtc[278:19893] rtc::<Peer:0x1477ec80, UID:2436266, r:Answer> Set remote ICE candidates, count: 20
2016-02-09 12:48:50:921 sample-videochat-webrtc[278:20551] rtc::<Peer:0x1477ec80, UID:2436266, r:Answer> Ice connection change:Connected
```

What am I missing here? Comparing my implementation and the sample's, I couldn't notice much difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has turned out to be a simple syntax-related mistake. When creating the session, I've used:

```
QBRTCSession *newSession = [QBRTCClient.instance
         createNewSessionWithOpponents:@[receipientStr] 
                    withConferenceType:QBRTCConferenceTypeVideo];
```

But the right syntax is

```
QBRTCSession *newSession = [QBRTCClient.instance 
         createNewSessionWithOpponents:@[@(receipientStr.intValue)]
                    withConferenceType:QBRTCConferenceTypeVideo];
```

With this modification, the video is fully working now.